# Python time estimate for higher number calaculation

Tags: python

How to figure out whether higher number calculations will work or not, if they are work then much time will it take to complete the execution in Python.

For example below with a=10 it printed a**a right away, and for second operation it did not error out or print anything on REPL.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> a = a ** a
>>> a
10000000000
>>> a = a ** a
```

Comment: It's going to "work", but *take a long time*.

Comment: @Jonathon. Ok but I am also trying to find out how to calculate how much time it may take.

Comment: If it would be proper calculation of integer power - would be about "log(a)" complexity, not sure what algorithm it actually uses.

Comment: It depends on the resources available: processor speed & architecture; other programs running; memory available; memory speed... In other words, run it and find out. If you want to estimate, try increasing a more slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

> Long integers have unlimited precision

And `int`s have changed to `long` automatically rather than overflow for [some time](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/):

```
>>> a = 50
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = a ** a
>>> type(a)
<type 'long'>
```

So your calculation will always return a value provided there is sufficient memory available.

The time taken increases with the `log` of the exponent. For details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377729/3707400).

Comment: @akixir Thanks. That is useful link. Will go through that