# Why v*v is faster than v**2 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I tried to measure the performance between `v*v` and `v**2`. And the result was just like below

```
# test was generated with randint(1, 999)

# 0.10778516498976387
print(timeit.timeit("sum([item*item for item in test])", number=10000, setup="from __main__ import test"))

# 0.35526178102009
print(timeit.timeit("sum([item**2 for item in test])", number=10000, setup="from __main__ import test"))
```

The reason that I started this experimentation was I don't want to do the same operation in the list comprehension.

Since the operator appears once, (for example, `(item-3) * (item*3)` and `(item-3)**2`) I thought `(item-3)**2` will be faster than `(item-3)*(item-3)`. But it was totally opposite.

Can anyone explain why?

[+] I used python3.6.0

Comment: How does the speed compare to `x**3` or `x**2.5`?

Comment: Because multiplication is faster than exponentiation. It would be nice if Python (or the underlying C math code, or the CPU) special-cased squares and maybe cubes, to do them using multiplication, but apparently it does not.

Comment: @StephenRauch Even x**4 has the same result with above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `*` is an arithmetic operation deeply rooted in processors and `**` is a wrapper for the `pow` function.

Using `k ** 2` has more overhead than `k * k` since python will internally call the pow function.

Comment: `**` isn't really a wrapper for the `pow()` function.  The builtin `pow()` function [calls `PyNumber_Power()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cfc8831f5ed607048679427f7d76d6cb4f8a2e8a/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1838) and [`**` is translated to bytecode `BINARY_POWER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/354626/1322401) and evaluated as a call to `PyNumber_Power()`.  So yes, `PyNumber_Power()` is slower than simple multiplication, but the call doesn't go `**` => `pow()` => `PyNumberPower()`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks for the information. Do you mean to say that `**` is translated to bytecode in place, i.e. there is no function call, or that it is translated to a call to `PyNumber_Power()` and not `pow()`?