Why do imaginary number calculations behave differently for exponents up to 100 and above 100?
The imaginary number i, or j in Python, means the square root of -1. So, i to the 4th or any multiple of 4 should be positive 1.
>>> (1j)**4
(1+0j)
>>> (1j)**96
(1+0j)
>>> (1j)**100
(1+0j)

Up until this point all is good, but once we get past 100, Python just bugs out. For example:
>>> (1j)**104
(1+7.842691359635767e-15j)

This messed up my calculations so much in an unexpected way. What explains this? I'm using Python 3.8.19.

7.84e-15 is basically zero. Are you looking for an explanation of why the value is not exactly zero (answer: floating point accuracy)? Or If you're trying to fix your calculations, I'd be helpful to post them.

@tripleee But don't you find it suspicious that Python gets the exact result for all exponents up to the nice number 100 and inaccurate results for all larger exponents? There's a special reason for that.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354421/how-is-implemented-in-python
Might be that it is switching over from integer to floating point math.
Also, title of the question is very unspecific and could be improved.

@BoppreH The question is "Why...?" and "Any explanations?" and the answer is more than just general "floating point accuracy" (it's irritating how quickly people just jump to that, dismissing other reasons).

For a workaround, you could define your complex numbers as 2x2 matrices in numpy, j =  np.array([[0, -1], [1, 0]]). Integer powers can then be calculated using eg. np.linalg.matrix_power(j, 1004) which results in 1 (as np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]]).

See the code, for integer exponents up to 100 it uses a different algorithm:
complex_pow(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, PyObject *z)
{
    ...
    // Check whether the exponent has a small integer value, and if so use
    // a faster and more accurate algorithm.
    if (b.imag == 0.0 && b.real == floor(b.real) && fabs(b.real) <= 100.0) {
        p = c_powi(a, (long)b.real);
    }
    else {
        p = _Py_c_pow(a, b);
    }
    ...

The special algorithm for the small exponents uses exponentiation by squaring, just multiplying 1j with itself and with the multiplication results, which is accurate:
c_powu(Py_complex x, long n)
{
    Py_complex r, p;
    long mask = 1;
    r = c_1;
    p = x;
    while (mask > 0 && n >= mask) {
        if (n & mask)
            r = _Py_c_prod(r,p);
        mask <<= 1;
        p = _Py_c_prod(p,p);
    }
    return r;
}

The general algorithm for exponents larger than 100 and non-integer exponents uses trigonometry and ends up involving inaccurate floats:
_Py_c_pow(Py_complex a, Py_complex b)
{
    ...
        vabs = hypot(a.real,a.imag);
        len = pow(vabs,b.real);
        at = atan2(a.imag, a.real);
        phase = at*b.real;
        if (b.imag != 0.0) {
            len /= exp(at*b.imag);
            phase += b.imag*log(vabs);
        }
        r.real = len*cos(phase);
        r.imag = len*sin(phase);
    ...

The at value for 1j mathematically is π/2, which isn't representable exactly as float. And then the phase and sin and thus the imaginary party of the result become inaccurate as well. See Why does math.cos(math.pi/2) not return zero? for more about that.
(I just noticed you mentioned using Python 3.8.19, while I looked up the current version, 3.12.6. The code slightly differs, but irrelevantly so, and the explanation is correct for both.)

Thanks, I wonder why they would do that as the general algorithm doesn't seem to be useable. What's the point of digging a hole like this?

I don't know. Looks like it has been like that from the start in 1996. You could ask in help.

This is a great answer to why it is broken, but I think the OP was looking for an actual fix, or workaround (and how does plopping out this comment only help python, which also is not getting addressed apparently).  Also, there are ways to handle pi, punting with "isn't representable exactly as float" is not always the best of these (again, more of an excuse than a fix).  peace out

The following code implements the behavior I've described in my comment.  In summary, if the base is purely imaginary, and the remainder of the exponent divided by four equals a whole number (exactly zero, one, two, or three), then the expression is handled exactly correctly according to well known complex variable math.  This approach avoids the need to hackingly declare the errant +7.842691359635767e-15j, for example from the OP, as "basically zero" as was done in one of the comments.
import cmath


def custom_complex_pow(base, exponent):


    # if base is purely imaginary
    # ??? optimize by checking for base.imag != 0
    if base.real == 0:


        # and if exponent/4 remainder is whole number 
        expo_modu_4 = exponent % 4


        # then leverage: j^4=1, j^3=-j, j^2=-1, j^1=j
        if expo_modu_4 == 0:
            return base ** exponent
        elif expo_modu_4 == 1:
            return base ** exponent * 1j
        elif expo_modu_4 == 2:
            return base ** exponent * -1
        elif expo_modu_4 == 3:
            return base ** exponent * -1j

    else:
        #  base not purely imaginary; do standard exponentiation
        return base ** exponent

